# FIRDatabase UISearchBar string for child

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, swift2

New to searchbars.

**Working:**

[String] "firstname" returns correct value when searching. If I have 3 people with "firstname" beginning with "G" (for example) table reloads with 3 cells.

**Problem:**

Although table reloads with proper cell values for "firstname", users.append(user) returns nil and wrong names are loaded onto the tableview.

**Assistance:**

How can I load correct names to tableview after search has been completed?

Here is my code:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange textSearched: String)->Void {

    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "firstname").queryStarting(atValue: textSearched).queryEnding(atValue: textSearched+"\u{f8ff}").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
                var users = [User]()
                let user = User()
                    print(user)
                for _ in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                        user.lastname = dictionary["firstname"] as? String
                        users.append(user)
                    }
                }
        self.users = users
        let search = searchCell()
        search.firstName.text = user.firstname
        self.attempReloadOfTable()
    }, withCancel: nil)
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! searchCell
    var user = User()
    user = users[indexPath.row]


    if let id = user.id{
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(id)
        ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            cell.lastName.text = user.lastname
            cell.firstName.text = user.firstname
        })
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is cell is returned before it's bound with user data in the block. Because code in the FIRBase result query block will be performed after `return cell` is executed.

i edited your code like this:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange textSearched: String)->Void {

    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "firstname").queryStarting(atValue: textSearched).queryEnding(atValue: textSearched+"\u{f8ff}").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        var users = [User]()
        for _ in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let user = User()
                user.lastname = dictionary["firstname"] as? String
                print(user)
                users.append(user)
            }
        }
        self.users = users
        let search = searchCell()
        search.firstName.text = user.firstname
        self.attempReloadOfTable()
    }, withCancel: nil)
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! searchCell
    let user = users[indexPath.row]

    cell.lastName.text = user.lastname
    cell.firstName.text = user.firstname

    return cell
}
```

Hope it'll work for you.

Comment: Okay fixed the error but now its not pulling value for "firstname" in search bar. Says 0 and returns zero cells.**if let dictionary = child.value as?[String: AnyObject] {  let user = User()**  <- this line is the culprit I know. (type nsfastenumerationiterator.element aka any ...)

Comment: Ok, so you should keep your code on `textDidChange` function, just change on `cellForRowAt` function.

Comment: Yup still not working. Just need to figure out how to load the correct user to the table. Everything else in the code works.